# Convergence/divergence of series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{(\log(1+n))^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum u_n\qquad u_n = \frac{1}{(\log(1+ n))^p}$$
Wolfram says it's convergent, my book proves it divergent, someone said it depends on p. Can anyone help with the actual answer?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't say it's convergent; perhaps you're confusing $\sum_p$ with $\sum_n$.

Comment: It's divergent for all $p\in\mathbb{R}$. To see it, use comparison test with $\sum\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @T.Bongers you were right I just noticed I was confusing between the two but how do I tell Wolfram that I need $\sum_n$ and not $s\um_p$

Comment: @Shaun I can't implement mathjax in title so I thought it would be better if I didn't put an equation but since you recommend so I did and I will keep this in my mind in the future. Thank you p.s. I am new here.

Comment: @rachitsaksena you can use mathjax in your title also.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously divergent: $(\log(n))^p<n$, for any $p>0$ and great enough $n$. On the other hand, if $p\leq 0$, the general term increases, thus the series diverges.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. You can find how to format your questions and answers [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

We have that for $p\le 0$

$$\frac{1}{(\log(1+ n))^p}\not \to 0$$

and the series doesn't converge.

For $p>0$, as an alternative, by Cauchy condensation test since

$$ 2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{(\log(1+ 2^n))^p} \sim \frac{2^n}{n^p(\log 2)^p} \to \infty$$

the condensed series $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ diverges and then also the given series diverges.